# How to prevent Notepad++ search to loop?

Tags: notepad++

I like when a search functionality tells me there's no more results when reaching the end of the file, rather than looping to the beginning of the file.

How can I do that in Notepad++? I can't find this option in the preferences menu.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Uncheck `Wrap around` when searching.

[image]

Comment: Simple by very very helpful!!!! :) Thank you.

Comment: I wanted the opposite - Notepad++ to search both ways rather than only Up or Down, and your answer helped me (in my case I had to Check the option). Thank you!